# PHP date function out format in Sunday, 15 of January

Tags: php

Input Date Format `DD-MM-YYYY`

```
Example 15-01-2012
```

I have a booking date stored in Session variable `$_SESSION['Date']` and date is in format `"DD-MM-YYYY"` I want to pass this date `date('l jS \of F Y')` so that i can get the out put in following as Sunday, 15 of January

Can i do this with date or i have to use some other function. I did google it but could not find much & confusing to me as i am new to php

Any reply of appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$date = date('l jS \of F Y', strtotime ( $_SESSION['Date'] ));
```

That's taking what you provided assuming you used [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for reference

Comment: It's simple just use the PHP date reference and put whatever you want in date() in place of your 'l jS \of F Y' - aslong as it's a realistic  date format

Comment: No, I mean the date format 12-12-2011 is ambiguous so strtotime doesn't know what the first two tokens refer to.

Comment: In that case you could break it down and then put it all in again.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks to other users who have also replied correctly.. But my logical choice was the first correct answer

Answer (score 6):

```
date('l jS \of F Y' ,strtotime("15-01-2012"));
```

You can use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert your stored string to a timestamp, which is then used as the second parameter of the date function.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/2q12Gv4t)

**Edit**

As Paul says, there is a safer way to do this using the `DateTime::createFromFormat` technique, but it is only available for PHP 5.3.0 and above.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-01-2012');
echo $date->format('l jS \of F Y');
?>
```

Comment: Sam as @ashley, the date format is ambiguous so it's safer to specify using date_create_from_format

Comment: @paul - edited to include your solution, although this only works on PHP >= 5.3

Comment: Yes that's definitely the issue with the DateTime object! exploding an reassembling would probably be the most widely supported

Comment: Official support for 5.2 ended in July 2010, so 5.3 as a requirement should not be a problem.

Comment: @Maerlyn - it shouldn't, but some providers are still using 5.2 or earlier. http://codepad.org/ is still on 5.2, hence the lack of a demo link for the second part of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) in the PHP Manual.

They have this example:

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Because the date format you are using is ambiguous, it's better to use the DateTime object. Think of the case of 12-12-2011.